# Cant POSTing value of CKEDITOR and Lose the Format of CKEDITOR [PHP with JQUERY AJAX ]

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ckeditor

I had  ckeditor's values, when those content contained special characters, in my case it happened when a `&nbsp;` was inside the content of the editor. It "killed" the url since `?data=blabla&nbsp;` is a malformed url..

```
var this = "conten=" + CKEDITOR.instances.tIsi.getData();
$.ajax({
    url: "action/prosesPOST.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: this,
    cache: false,
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(datanya);
        if (msg == "yes") {} else {
            alert("Failde to Update data," + msg);
        }
    }
});​
```

and i change it be

> var this ={
>   conten: CKEDITOR.instances.tIsi.getData();
>   }

and viola i can update and posting that but all format of ckeditor lose when showed it on ckeditor on showing on table.

Comment: I would not suggest you to use `this` as a variable name in the fist place. And can you show the expected format from the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=================================== SOLVED ====================================

the problems is when i am posting it like this :

> var this = "conten=" + CKEDITOR.instances.tIsi.getData();

ckeditor value unshowed,i know it because use alert(this); before ajax sending and value is null
when i am using :

> var this = {conten: CKEDITOR.instances.tIsi.getData()}

data not null and inserted to database but my format style lose like "margin","align",etc make it like string,ex : **BOLD** be => < b >BOLD < / b >

and i solved this with simple trick make it be *html_entity_decode($value_on_database)* changing the object data to normal when i want showing it on ckeditor or the other.

CHEERS :))

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how if I understood your question correctly. Is the issue with POSTing data or is the data malformed somehow? Meaning is it not as you expected on the server?

Does the following work (Edited to be more complete)?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "action/prosesPOST.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {conten: CKEDITOR.instances.tIsi.getData();}
    cache: false,
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(datanya);
        if (msg == "yes") {} else {
            alert("Failde to Update data," + msg);
        }
    }
});​
```

Is the data posted correctly? If you debug the data in PHP, is it as you expected? How do you output the data if it looks OK before using it?

I would also use another variable name rather than "this" as it already has an expected meaning in JavaScript.

Comment: the problems is when i am posting it like this var this = "conten=" + CKEDITOR.instances.tIsi.getData();